# short if statement in itemTpl configuration Sencha Touch 2

Tags: if-statement, sencha-touch-2, itemtemplate

I was wondering, is it possible to state an if statement (short or not) inside the itemTpl configuration of a List in Sencha Touch.

```
//My Model
Ext.define('ListItem', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: ['number', 'someBoolean']
            }
        });
//The List
var MyList = Ext.create("Ext.List", {
        itemTpl : "{number} <br />"+
                    //THIS LINE BELOW IS WHAT ITS ALL ABOUT
                ("{someBoolean}")? + "The boolean was true" : +"It was false" ,
        store: oListStore,
    });
```

This results in a List filled with items representing NaN on the screen.

Is there a way to program around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Ext.XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)

Here's an example

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<p>Name: {name}</p>',
    '<p>Kids: ',
    '<tpl for="kids">',
        '<tpl if="age &gt; 1">',
            '<p>{name}</p>',
            '<p>Dad: {parent.name}</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl></p>'
),
```

Hope this helps