# adding images to itemTpl based on if condition

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to add image in itemTpl depends on "if " statement.  Can anyone pls help me to solve this issue?

here is my code,

```
//Controller
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){  
 //Storing our values in Array      

var st =  {
'Amount':jsonarr.AgentTransactionResult[i].Amount,
'TransactionId':jsonarr.AgentTransactionResult[i].TransactionId,
'Status':jsonarr.AgentTransactionResult[i].Status,
'Date':jsonarr.AgentTransactionResult[i].Date,
            };  
//Adding our array to LocalStore(localStorage)
var localStore = Ext.getStore('transstore');
localStore.add(st);
localStore.sync();
localStore.load();  
}//for loop
```

---

```
//View

xtype: 'list', store : 'transstore', html:'<table border="0" width="100%"><th><td width="25%">Amount</td><td width="25%">Status</td><td width="25%">Date</td><td width="25%">Transaction Id</td></th></table>', itemTpl:
'<table border="0" width="100%">'+
'<tr>'+
'<td width="10%"><font size="2" color="#000000"><b>{Amount}</b></font></td>'+
'<td width="20%"><font size="2" color="#003300"><b>{Status}</b></font></td>'+
'<td width="23%"><font size="2" color="#003300"><b>{Date}</b></font></td>'+
'<td width="8%"><font size="2" color="#003300"><b>{TransactionId}</b></font></td>'+
'</tr>'+
'</table>'.
```

and Ive to display my Status in image format. if(status=="Success") return "img url" else return "another img url". I've retrieved the status from webservice and I don't know how to change the image. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257934/short-if-statement-in-itemtpl-configuration-sencha-touch-2).

Also your questions are much easier to answer when they are formatted.

If you cannot get that to work re-format your example and let me know what it is you are checking with your if statement and I will try to put an example together for you.

Good Luck, Brad